# Is there a computer science theory behind automatic source code generation

Tags: code-generation

The OpenAPI [specification](https://swagger.io/specification/) aims at standardizing the representation of REST based systems in json and yaml formats. A short version of the [petstore](http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) is below:

```
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
 "info": {},
 "host": "petstore.swagger.io",
 "basePath": "/v2",
  "tags": [],
  "schemes": [
 "http"
 ],
 "paths": {},
 "securityDefinitions": {},
 "definitions": {},
 "externalDocs": {
 "description": "Find out more about Swagger",
 "url": "http://swagger.io"
 }
}
```

Based on this document, client and server stubs can be generated in different programming languages/frameworks using the [OpenAPI codegen project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). Is there a computer science theory behind this ? **To be more precise**, I want to specifically know if there are theoretical concepts behind taking an input, (in this case a json/yaml document) and getting a source code representation in one or more programming languages that represents the initial input ?

Comment: @DavidRicherby +1 for the wikipedia reference. It included the information I was looking for. I  understand now that `generative programming` , (which falls under `automatic programming`), deals with `automatic code generation`. I also  found some academic papers that give more insights into the theory and related research :) I can accept your answer if you move it to the appropriate place.

Comment: OK. We generally discourage answers that are just a link to some other resource so, if somebody posts a proper answer that isn't just a link, please unaccept mine and give them the credit that I don't deserve. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about it but the field as a whole is called "[automatic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming)", which should give you pointers of where to look.

Comment: If anyone has an answer that isn't just a link, please do post it!